# Incorporate javadoc URL for external jar dependency in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, javadoc

I've searched for similar questions already asked, but most have been related to *generating* new java documentation using javadoc for all of the included dependencies.

My question is more basic - I just want to be able to view the javadoc documentation for an external library in Eclipse when using the "Ctrl+Space" or hovering over an object/method.

For example: 
I have a dependency for the "commons-cli" library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

By default though, I am not able to view the API documentation for the classes located in this library. I can do this manually, by using the Project Explorer to navigating to the "commons-cli-1.3.jar" file located in Java Resources->Library->Maven Dependencies and then specifying the URL (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/) for the javadoc in its property dialog box.

Is there a way to incorporate this information into the maven pom.xml file? That way, I don't have to do this manually for every dependency and also it works for anyone checking out my project to their own computer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have m2e installed, it should do it automatically when you try to view a class file of that library... If not, you can always right click the project and select "Maven > Download Javadoc" and then "Download sources".

Comment: Thanks. I don't have m2e installed, but the Download Javadoc worked for me. If you want to copy your comment as a reply, I will mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:sources` which downloads the sources for the libraries. Check Maven repo dir (normally `~/.m2` ) if you have sources there - there should be jar with the same name as the lib artifact but appended with `-sources`. Like this:

[image]

If this is the case and you still don't see the javadocs in IDE then you should setup your IDE to use Maven repo as a source for sources.

Comment: I believe this is the same as right clicking on the project and selecting Maven -> Download sources, which downloads both source and javadoc. Just out of curiosity, how can you run this command `mvn dependency:sources` from within Eclipse?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Eclipse Maven plugin. When I used Eclipse I used command line/terminal and now with Idea I do the same. I prefer not to rely on build tool plugins in IDE. Using terminal gives you the control you need.